# google connect error

Tags: http-status-code-404

I am trying to login using google account connection..
but it show me an error

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /market/modules/connect/easyauth.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at dkakeen.com Port 80
```

I contacted the developer and he said :

> Your hosting probably blocks certain strings in urls, this is why you
>   get the Forbidden error. You will probably see more information about
>   the error in the error log in your hosting account. You could also ask
>   your hosting support if they have such security measures to block
>   parts of urls, and if they can disable them for you. This is the full
>   url that the script is trying to access and it cannot:
>
> http://dkakeen.com/market/modules/connect/easyauth.php?auth=google&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2012-10-10T12%3A44%3A29ZJuJ_ahE5fLQx5Q&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdkakeen.com%2Fmarket%2Fmodules%2Fconnect%2Feasyauth.php%3Fauth%3Dgoogle&openid.assoc_handle=AMlYA9Vntq_WQ9WEb85GI5Z32JS4E47Z6sRbimCf503Eht-w7zDq_wTZ&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.namePerson_first%2Cext1.value.namePerson_first%2Cext1.type.contact_email%2Cext1.value.contact_email%2Cext1.type.namePerson_last%2Cext1.value.namePerson_last&openid.sig=qVXb27ds2obrWeehvGRgUaZYCKM%3D&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawn507OyS3bO50BXsj02tgccdznijvVpyHY&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawn507OyS3bO50BXsj02tgccdznij
>   vVpyHY&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response&openid.ext1.type.namePerson_first=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Ffirst&openid.ext1.value.namePerson_first=Classifieds&openid.ext1.type.contact_email=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.value.contact_email=classifiedsaddict%40gmail.com&openid.ext1.type.namePerson_last=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Flast&openid.ext1.value.namePerson_last=Addict&openid.ns.ext2=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fui%2F1.0&openid.ext2.mode=popup

How I fix it?